# Cannot read the property 'ReactCurrentOwner' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

```js
import React from 'react';
import AddOption from './AddOption';
import Action from './Action';
import Header from './Header';
import Options from './Options';
import OptionModal from './OptionModal';

export default class IndecisionApp extends React.Component {

 constructor(){
  super();

  this.state = {
   options: [],
   selectedOption: undefined
  };
  this.handleDeleteOptions = this.handleDeleteOptions.bind(this);
  this.handleClearSelectedOption = this.handleClearSelectedOption.bind(this);
  this.handleDeleteOption = this.handleDeleteOption.bind(this);
  this.handlePick = this.handlePick.bind(this);
  this.handleAddOption = this.handleAddOption.bind(this);
 }

 handleDeleteOptions(){
  console.log('handleDeleteOptions');
  this.setState(() => ({ options: [] }));
 };

 handleClearSelectedOption(){
  this.setState(() => ({ selectedOption: undefined }));
 }

 handleDeleteOption(optionToRemove){
  console.log('handleDeleteOption');

  this.setState((prevState) => ({ 
   options: prevState.options.filter((option) => optionToRemove !== option)
  }));
  };

 handlePick(){
  const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.options.length);
  const option = this.state.options[randomNum];
  this.setState(() => ({
   selectedOption: option
  }));
 };
 handleAddOption(option) {
    
  console.log(option)
  if (!option) {
   return 'Enter valid value to add item';
  } else if (this.state.options.indexOf(option) > -1) {
   return 'This option already exists'; 
  }

  var len = 0;

  if (this.state.options !== undefined){
   len = this.state.options.length;
  }
  if (len > 2)
  {
   this.setState((prevState) => ({
    options: prevState.options.slice(len - 2, len).concat(option)
   }));
  }
  else {
   this.setState((prevState) => ({
    options: prevState.options.concat(option)
   }))
  }
 };

 componentDidMount() {
  console.log('In componentDidMount');

  try {
   
   const json = localStorage.getItem('options');
   const options = JSON.parse(json);

   if (options) {
    this.setState(() => ({ options }));
   }
  } catch (e) {
   // Do nothing at all
  }
 }
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState.options.length !== this.state.options.length) {
   const json = JSON.stringify(this.state.options);
   localStorage.setItem('options', json);
  }
 }
 componentWillUnmount() {
  console.log('componentWillUnmount');
 }

 render() {
  const subtitle = 'Put your life in the computer hands';

  

  return (
   <div>
    <Header subtitle={subtitle} />
    <div className="container">
     <Action 
     hasOptions={this.state.options.length > 0}
     handlePick={this.handlePick}
    />

    <div className="widget">
     <Options
     options={this.state.options}
     handleDeleteOptions={this.handleDeleteOptions}
     handleDeleteOption={this.handleDeleteOption}
     />

     <AddOption
     handleAddOption={this.handleAddOption}
     />

    </div>
   </div>

   <OptionModal
   selectedOption={this.state.selectedOption}
   handleClearSelectedOption={this.handleClearSelectedOption}
   /> 
   </div>
  );
 }
}
```

```css
{
 "name": "indecision-app",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "main": "index.js",
 "author": "Nishanth Battula",
 "license": "IIT",
 "scripts": {
  "serve": "live-server public/",
  "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server --env.dev",
  "build": "webpack",
  "build:dev": "webpack"
 },
 "dependencies": {
  "babel-cli": "6.24.1",
  "babel-core": "6.25.0",
  "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
  "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.24.1",
  "babel-preset-env": "1.5,2",
  "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
  "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
  "live-server": "^1.2.0",
  "node-sass": "4.5.3",
  "normalize.css": "7.0.0",
  "react": "15.6.1",
  "react-dom": "2.2.2",
  "react-modal": "6.0.6",
  "react-watermark": "0.0.3",
  "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
  "style-loader": "^0.19.1",
  "validator": "8.0.0",
  "webpack": "^3.1.0",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.1"
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

I have a small React App in place. It has been in a working condition for a while, however, after the addition of code for a small feature, I see the TypeError 'Cannot read the property ReactCurrentOwner of undefined'. The sequence of actions I performed in the project are:

- yarn install
- yarn build (this is equivalent to *webpack*)
- yarn serve (this is equivalent to *liveserver* public/)

For the first step, viz. yarn install, there are several options showing up for choice of libraries related to React. It confuses me to choose the appropriate option.

It will be nice if someone among you can help clear the TypeError in web-console, so that I can view the app properly.

Comment: Can you include the JS file that throws this error?

Comment: There is probably some inconsistency in the versions of your dependencies. As a quick thing to try now, you can delete your `node_modules` and run all the commands to start the project again. If it doesnt help, please include your `package.json` as well as more info about what error you see in the console.

Comment: I have just added the package.json file. Please check.

Comment: Is it an option for you to upgrade to `react` 16 or you have to keep the current version of `react` in your project? you can find more info on this [github thread](https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion/issues/447).